# Make header and footer files to include multiple html pages can we do same in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

As we do in html including the header & footer in multiple html pages. Can we do same in WordPress by usig jQuery.But in this case i need to add header & footer directly from html site. My code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#head").load("../header.html");
  $("#foot").load("../footer.html"); 
});
</script>
```

With this code header & footer are showing, but images are not showing, navigation menu isn't working.

Comment: Why you are using jQuery to include content? Why not use PHP `include`?

Comment: ...or `get_header();`...since it's a WordPress site.

Answer (score 0):

In your `#head` div just use `get_header();`

In your `#foot` div just use `get_footer();`

This is the way you must include header and footer in WordPress.